Adding switch in-line between power bank and Raspberry Pi
I need to add a toggle switch between a Raspberry Pi4, and a power bank I'm using to power it.
I have two USB-C connectors on PCBs, soldered the pins together between the two boards (CC1,CC2,GND,d+,d-), and for VBUS, I've soldered them to a switch.
When I use a normal charge adapter, it works fine. But, when I use the power bank (ugreen 20,000 mAh, 45W port), it doesn't work. Also, the 18W port on this power bank will power the rPi.
My guess is that some capability sensor on the CC lines is detecting an incompatibility. Perhaps I inadvertently changed the line resistance. However, I literally shorted all lines to the matching lines, and it doesn't work.
Can someone please explain why it works for the adapter, but not the powerbank 45W port? I'd like to understand how I could have screwed this up.
The white wires go to a simple switch. You can't see because it's glued upside down, but the pins are jumped straight across.

Power bank info:
https://ca.ugreen.com/products/ugreen-145w-power-bank-for-laptop


Hello and welcome.  Can I recommend you edit in a photo of what you're describing.  The difficulty is there's some mismatch between what you're expecting and what you have, and a photo would really help us understand where that is.

To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to include a) A schematic of the connections between the boards. b) Links to the datasheet for the power bank.

Thanks for suggestions.

So, to clarify, you’re saying that the USB-A output of the power bank works with your breakout/switch solution, but neither the USB-C1 nor USB-C2 work with the same solution?

Yes, that's correct. I'm guessing it's the lower power  ports only which work. The higher power ports do nothing.

The raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics show a 5K1 pull-down connected to CC1 and CC2 on the USB-C power input connector. Have any resistors connected to the CC lines been removed on both USB-C breakout boards? On one in the picture looks line R1 and R4 have been removed, but from the picture can't see the other side. If you have a multi-meter you could try disconnecting the USB-C cables from the breakout boards and measure the resistance from the CC pins to ground and VBUS to check for any resistance.

In response to the following part of the question:

My guess is that some capability sensor on the CC lines is detecting an incompatibility.

The Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (REDUCED) schematics show the USB-C POWER IN has connected the CC1 and CC2 pin together as the net USB_CC with a single 5K1 R79 pull-down:



The Universal Serial Bus Type-C Cable and Connector Specification Release 2.4 downloaded from usb.org has the following in section 4.5.1.2.1 Detecting a Valid Source-to-Sink Connection:

Initially, a Source exposes independent Rp terminations on its CC1 and CC2 pins, and a Sink exposes independent Rd terminations on its CC1 and CC2 pins, the Source-to-Sink combination of this circuit configuration represents a valid connection.

Where the Raspberry Pi 4 will be the Sink. Since the Raspberry Pi 4 has connected the CC1 and CC2 pins together, they will no longer be exposing independent Rd terminations as far as the USB-C power delivery source in the power bank is concerned.
Although I don't know the internal implementation of the USB-C1 or USB-C2 on the power bank, my guess is that the Raspberry Pi 4 connecting the CC1 and CC2 pins together results in the UCB-C source in the power bank thinking there is no sink connected.
Since there are two USB-C breakout boards used, and which appear to have R1 and R4 removed which are probably for 5K1 pull-downs on the CC1 and CC2 pins perhaps the following would work:

Remove the CC1 and CC2 connections between the two USB-C breakout boards.
Fit 5K1 resistors R1 and R4 on the USB-C breakout board connected to the power bank.


Thank you for the in-depth explanation. I will try your suggestions.

These two suggestions worked perfectly. It also fixed an issue where I couldn't turn the rPi back on without disconnecting. So, thank you very much!
